# How do I 'squash' the values in a DataFrame that I know only has one item per row into a Series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan, series

I have a DataFrame which I have confirmed has no more than one value in each row (the rest are np.nan).  How can I turn this into a one-dimensional array or Series?

Say this is my starting array:

```
In [7]: import pandas as pd

In [8]: data = [
    [np.nan, 9.0, np.nan],
    [np.nan, np.nan, 3.0],
    [np.nan, np.nan, 5.0],
    [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
    [1.0, np.nan, np.nan]
]

In [9]: a = pd.DataFrame(data)

In [10]: a
Out[10]: 
     0    1    2
0  NaN  9.0  NaN
1  NaN  NaN  3.0
2  NaN  NaN  5.0
3  NaN  NaN  NaN
4  1.0  NaN  NaN
```

And I want to create the following Series b:

```
In [17]: b
Out[17]: 
0    9.0
1    3.0
2    5.0
3    NaN
4    1.0
dtype: float64
```

I've written some code to do it:

```
In [14]: m = a.notnull()

In [15]: m
Out[15]: 
       0      1      2
0  False   True  False
1  False  False   True
2  False  False   True
3  False  False  False
4   True  False  False

In [16]: for i, row in a.iterrows():
        for j, v in row.iteritems():
                if m.iloc[i, j]:
                        b[i] = v
```

But there must be an easier way!

I tried using `np.max` and `np.sum` but they both return an empty (nan) array.

Comment: Thanks everyone, and thanks jezrael for summarizing everyone's ideas below and running the timings.  They all work well but I'm afraid I didn't set up the example very well; for the actual dataframe that I am working with, the values may be numeric or non-numeric.  So the f(x) and user(dataDF) solutions are the only ones that work in actual practice I think.

Comment: Question: Should I now update the question to reflect this or would that cause confusion given the answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`first_valid_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.first_valid_index.html), but need condition if all values are `NaN`:

```
def f(x):
    if x.first_valid_index() is None:
        return None
    else:
        return x[x.first_valid_index()]

b = a.apply(f, axis=1)

print (b)
0    9.0
1    3.0
2    5.0
3    NaN
4    1.0
dtype: float64
```

Another solution with [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sum.html) and [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
print (pd.Series(np.where(a.notnull().any(1), a.sum(1), np.nan)))
0    9.0
1    3.0
2    5.0
3    NaN
4    1.0
dtype: float64
```

Solution with `np.max` works nice also:

```
print (np.max(a, axis=1))
0    9.0
1    3.0
2    5.0
3    NaN
4    1.0
dtype: float64
```

Or simplier and fastest only [`max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.max.html):

```
print (a.max(axis=1))
0    9.0
1    3.0
2    5.0
3    NaN
4    1.0
dtype: float64
```

**Timings**:

```
a = pd.concat([a]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [133]: %timeit (a.max(axis=1))
100 loops, best of 3: 2.81 ms per loop

In [134]: %timeit (np.max(a, axis=1))
100 loops, best of 3: 2.83 ms per loop

In [135]: %timeit (pd.Series(np.where(a.notnull().any(1), a.sum(1), np.nan)))
100 loops, best of 3: 3.18 ms per loop

In [136]: %timeit (a.apply(f, axis=1))
1 loop, best of 3: 2.18 s per loop

#http://stackoverflow.com/a/39011722/2901002
In [137]: %timeit a.max(axis=1, skipna=True)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.84 ms per loop
```

---

```
def user(dataDF):

    squash = pd.Series(index=dataDF.index)
    for col in dataDF.columns.values:
        squash.update(dataDF[col])
    return squash

print(user(a))
In [151]: %timeit (user(a))
100 loops, best of 3: 7.75 ms per loop
```

EDIT by comment:

If values are not numeric, you can use:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [
    [np.nan, 'a', np.nan],
    [np.nan, np.nan, 'b'],
    [np.nan, np.nan, 'c'],
    [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
    ['d', np.nan, np.nan]
]

a = pd.DataFrame(data)
print (a)
     0    1    2
0  NaN    a  NaN
1  NaN  NaN    b
2  NaN  NaN    c
3  NaN  NaN  NaN
4    d  NaN  NaN

print (a.fillna('').sum(axis=1).mask(a.isnull().all(1)))
0      a
1      b
2      c
3    NaN
4      d
dtype: object
```

Comment: Please see my comment above on the original question.

Comment: All values in DaraFrame is not numeric? Of some columns are numeric and some non?

Comment: Basically I need a script that will work with a dataframe containing either numeric or non-numeric data (and nans).  The background to this is that I am grouping columns of data from different data sources into single columns.

Comment: Thank you for accepting! Hmmm, first solution works with numeric and non numeric also.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`pd.DataFrame.max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.max.html) or [`pd.DataFrame.sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) with the `skipna` value set to `True`:

> **skipna**: boolean, default True; Exclude NA/null values. If an entire row/column is NA, the result will be NA

So, you should try

```
a.max(axis=1, skipna=True)
```

Comment: Hmmm, for me it have not desired output, because if use `a.sum(axis=1, skipna=True)` get `0` instead `NaN` in row with index `3`. For you it works nice? I use python 3 and last verison of pandas.

Comment: It looks like bug. For me works nice `print (a.max(axis=1, skipna=True))`

Comment: @jezrael Thanks, updated the answer. I remember using the exact same thing in the past (can't remember if `max` or `sum`, though), but am not now near a computer.

Comment: Yes, but then please change `axis=0` to `axis=1`

Comment: Please see my comment above on the original question.

Answer (score 1):

I would make use of the [update()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.update.html) function. For a variable number of columns:

```
dataDF = pd.DataFrame(data)

squash = pd.Series(index=dataDF.index)
for col in dataDF.columns.values:
    squash.update(dataDF[col])

print (squash)

0    9.0
1    3.0
2    5.0
3    NaN
4    1.0
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

Comment: For me it does not work. If use `print (a.ix[:,0].update(a.ix[:,1]))` it return `None`. do you test it with DataFrame `a`?

Comment: I have adjusted the example. My dataDF is your Dataframe a. Can you do a speed comparison for us? thank you

Comment: Added timings to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way using Numpy's [nonzero](https://numpy.org/doc/1.24/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html) method, which can be used to find the indices of the non-NaN values.

```
b = pd.Series(np.full(a.shape[0], np.nan))
i, j = a.notnull().values.nonzero()
b.iloc[i] = a.values[(i, j)]
```

Output:

```
0    9.0
1    3.0
2    5.0
3    NaN
4    1.0
dtype: float64
```

This is safer if you aren't sure that there is no more than one value in each row because it will raise an exception if there is.